# Any idea on how the event loop works in Pysimplegui? Can't figure out disabling buttons based on other inputs

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

So I am having many issues with Pysimplegui's event loops, I'm trying to disable a button based on the lack of input in another part of the code (in this case it's the lack of selection of at least one checkbox if the radio button above is pressed [but I should apply the same logic if a folder is not selected]).
I tried looking everywhere and either I can't find a solution or people apparently manage to get through based on the cookbook (which I tried and can't).

The code i tried is the following:

This is the part regarding the Radio buttons:

```
layout_1 = [
# things before...
    [sg.Radio('CSV/JSON:', "OUTPUT", default=False, key='-OutputFile-', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Checkbox('Output as CSV', key='-OutputCSV-', disabled=True)],
    [sg.Checkbox('Output as JSON', key='-OutputJSON-', disabled=True)],
    [sg.Text('Select a folder: ')], [sg.FolderBrowse(key='-Folder-')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Column([[sg.Button("Submit", disabled=False, key='-Submit-'), sg.Cancel()]], element_justification='c'), sg.Push()]
]

window_2 = sg.Window('Info', layout_1, finalize = True)
```

Then I have this while loop, which in theory, should basically disable the ability to select the output if '-OutputFile-' is False and, in case none of the two available outputs available (CSV or JSON) are selected, disable the Submit button as well. Thing is the disabling of the choices works but the Submit button is never disabled and can't be clicked.

```
while True:
    event_2, values_table = window_2.read()
    if event_2 in (sg.WIN_CLOSE, 'Cancel', 'Submit', None):
        break
    elif event_2 == '-OutputFile-':
        window_2['-OutputJSON-'].update(disabled = False)
        window_2['-OutputCSV-'].update(disabled = False)
        if window_2['-OutputFile-'] and not window_2['-OutputCSV-'] and not window_2['-OutputJSON-']:
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=True)
            sg.popup('Select an output', keep_on_top=True)
    elif event_2 == '-OutputNone-':
        window_2['-OutputJSON-'].update(disabled=True)
        window_2['-OutputCSV-'].update(disabled=True)
window_2.close()
```

I should note that the code works without the part in the loop about the Submit button, but I need that part as well.

Another thing I tried is using is False instead of not in the part not working.

This is what the window looks like:
[image: This is what the window looks like]

PS: there might be grammatical errors in the code, unfortunately I had to copy it by and, even if I checked, there might be some error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pysimplegui at all but `finalize = True` part in the first code block made me think that the attributes of elements could not be changed. Finalizing again after the update might solve your problem (but again, I'm not sure.).

Comment: don't you get error message when you run code in console? You forgot `]` in some lines. Always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you forgot `)` in some lines in `layout` and you forgot `]` in some lines in `while`-loop. Your code should generate error without showing window. Show correct code. It makes no sense to check code if you put wrong code. We can't say which element really makes problem in your real code.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you need `.Get()` in `window_2['-OutputCSV-'].Get()` and `window_2['-OutputJSON-'].Get()` to check if elements are selected. You would need also check other events to activate `Submit` when you select JSON o CSV, and other code to deactivate `Submit` when you deselect both values.

Comment: There is no event when the user clicks the "Cancel" button when choosing a file.  Instead of using FileBrowse, your a normal button.  When user clicks the button, you'll call popup_get_file and can then determine if they've not chosen a file.  Open an Issue with the project for help?

Comment: @furas as I stated, I copied it by hand; unfortunately I missed some parenthesis during the process. It should be fine now as I checked what you found and all the code again.

Comment: @furas I also tried print debugging but every time the program crashed...

Comment: using `print()` you should see what values you have when it crashs. And  this should show you if you have correct values.

Comment: @MikefromPSG I don't understand, that part of the code works properly; when I press Browse, it opens the folder selection menu. The problem has to do with the fact that I want to show a pop-up and grey out the 'Submit' button when the user selects 'CSV/JSON' but none of the checkboxes is checked.

Comment: Please open an issue on the project's GitHub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.Get()` in `window_2['-OutputCSV-'].Get()` and `window_2['-OutputJSON-'].Get()` to check if elements are selected.

```
if not window_2['-OutputCSV-'].Get() and not window_2['-OutputJSON-'].Get():
    window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=True)
    sg.popup('Select an output', keep_on_top=True)
```

You would need also code to activate `Submit` when you select `JSON` or `CSV`, and deactivate `Submit` when you deselect both elements.

```
    elif event_2 in ('-OutputCSV-', '-OutputJSON-'):
        if not window_2['-OutputCSV-'].Get() and not window_2['-OutputJSON-'].Get():
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=True)
            #sg.popup('Select an output', keep_on_top=True)
        else:
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=False)
```

---

Full working example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout_1 = [
# things before...
    [sg.Radio('None:', "OUTPUT", default=False, key='-OutputNone-', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Radio('CSV/JSON:', "OUTPUT", default=False, key='-OutputFile-', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Checkbox('Output as CSV', key='-OutputCSV-', disabled=True, enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Checkbox('Output as JSON', key='-OutputJSON-', disabled=True, enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Text('Select a folder: ')], [sg.FolderBrowse(key='-Folder-')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Column([[sg.Button("Submit", disabled=False, key='-Submit-'), sg.Cancel()]], element_justification='c'), sg.Push()]
]

window_2 = sg.Window('Info', layout_1, finalize=True)

while True:
    event_2, values_table = window_2.read()
    print(event_2)
    if event_2 in ('Cancel', 'Submit', None):
        break
    elif event_2 == '-OutputFile-':
        window_2['-OutputJSON-'].update(disabled = False)
        window_2['-OutputCSV-'].update(disabled = False)
        
        if not window_2['-OutputCSV-'].Get() and not window_2['-OutputJSON-'].Get():
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=True)
            sg.popup('Select an output', keep_on_top=True)
            
    elif event_2 == '-OutputNone-':
        window_2['-OutputJSON-'].update(disabled=True)
        window_2['-OutputCSV-'].update(disabled=True)

    elif event_2 in ('-OutputCSV-', '-OutputJSON-'):
        if not window_2['-OutputCSV-'].Get() and not window_2['-OutputJSON-'].Get():
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=True)
            #sg.popup('Select an output', keep_on_top=True)
        else:
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=False)

window_2.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally forgot about the enable_effects for the checkboxes! It works smoothly now!

Any idea on how to check if the 'Folder' wasn't selected in the case that an output is wanted? Apparently I can't use `.Get()` on `window_2['-Folder-]` because it's a button

Comment: you have to check `values_table['-Folder-']`

Comment: `if not window_2['-OutputCSV-'].Get() and not window_2['-OutputJSON-'].Get():
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=True)
            sg.popup('Select an output', keep_on_top=True)
         if values_table['-Folder-'] is None:
            window_2['-Submit-'].update(disabled=True)
            sg.popup('Select a folder', keep_on_top=True)`
I tried this way and didn't work, I also tried using .Get() on values_table['-Folder-'] with no results, unfortunately.
Plus, no pop-up shows up, either in the new or the previously implemented code...

Comment: If you want to check if button `Cancel` was click in window `Browser` then you can't do it - it doesn't generate event for this. In normal `Tkinter` it would return `None` from window `Browser`. Maybe it needs some extra option in Pysimplegui but it would need to check in documentation or in source code.

Comment: if you have new problem then better create new question on new page - you will have more place to put code and description, and code will be more readable, and new people may see it - so new people may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not check the code in detail, but following statement is wrong. Should check them by `values[...]`, not `window_2[...]` which is the element.

```py
if window_2['-OutputFile-'] and not window_2['-OutputCSV-'] and not window_2['-OutputJSON-']
```

Example Code:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkBlue4')

layout = [
    [sg.Radio('None',     'Group', default=True,  key='R1', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Radio('CSV/JSON', 'Group',                key='R2', enable_events=True),
     sg.Checkbox('CSV',            default=False, key='C1', enable_events=True, disabled=True),
     sg.Checkbox('JSON',           default=False, key='C2', enable_events=True, disabled=True)],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Submit',               key='B1',                     disabled=True)]
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
r1, r2, c1, c2, b1 = [window[key] for key in ('R1', 'R2', 'C1', 'C2', 'B1')]

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event in ('R1', 'R2'):
        disabled = False if values['R2'] else True
        c1.update(disabled=disabled)
        c2.update(disabled=disabled)
        state = False if not disabled and values['C1'] and values['C2'] else True
        b1.update(disabled=state)

    elif event in ('C1', 'C2'):
        state = False if values['C1'] and values['C2'] else True
        b1.update(disabled=state)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Tried to do so but it said the keys didn't exist

Comment: The sample code worked OK for me.